# Reattribute the same variable several times according to the variable of another column

Tags: r, for-loop

I come to seek your help because despite various research, I don't find similar cases.

To summarize, I am working on a data.frame (of which I present a part) in which I have two categories differentiated by the symbol in the first column by the symbols "-" and "*"

I have an individual identifier (df $ V8) assigned to all individuals marked "*" (df $ V1)

I would like to assign this identifier to individuals marked "-" (df $ V1) according to the variable contained in the column df $ V7

```
> df
  V1       V7           V8
1  - 31404168         <NA>
2  - 11564168         <NA>
3  - 11563520         <NA>
4  * 11563520 0034 3520 03
5  * 11564168 0034 4168 03
6  * 31404168 0034 4168 04
```

I wanted to try with a loop but I remain stuck on the writing of it

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
 if (df$V7[i]== "x" & df$V8[i] == <NA>){
  df$V8[i]<-df$V8...  
 } else {df$V8[i]<-df$V8[i]}
}
```

What I am looking for:

```
> df
  V1       V7           V8
 1  - 31404168 0034 4168 04
 2  - 11564168 0034 4168 03
 3  - 11563520 0034 3520 03
 4  * 11563520 0034 3520 03
 5  * 11564168 0034 4168 03
 6  * 31404168 0034 4168 04
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You're missing out on the power of R by using a for loop. I'm assuming here that every V7 appears twice, once with a "*" and once with a "-", and also that V8 is a string class:

```
library(dplyr)
df<- group_by(df, V7) %>% 
    mutate(V8=max(V8, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Here's what's going on here: using the dplyr package, I sorted `df` into groups based on V7 (so ideally every group has two cases). I then put into V8, regardless of the V1, whichever V8 that isn't NA (I used `max()` here purely for convenience).

Remember that in R, the default is for every action to occur for every line, so if you just want to go over the entire array, or a subset of it, and perform some action, there's no need for `for` loops.

Comment: Thanks,

Because after my post, i used "arrange" but it didn't work as well as your proposition